# Create a new column based on existing columns with a function

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I'm working with this `data.frame` and I would like to create a new column called "predicted" whose values are calculated with this formula:

```
rbeta(1,alfa,beta)
```

[image]

Here's some example data:

```
data<-structure(list(mu = c(0.548403436247893, 0.944576856539307, 0.72167558981069, 
                            0.721610257581108, 0.987386739865525), kappa = c(77.8230430114621, 
                                                                             26.2939905325391, 28.0123299600893, 24.5166019567386, 42.8769003810988
                            ), alfa = c(42.6784242067533, 24.8366949231, 20.2158147459191, 
                                        17.6914314530156, 42.336082882832), beta = c(35.1446188047087, 
                                                                                     1.45729560943902, 7.7965152141702, 6.82517050372298, 0.540817498266786
                                        )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use package `purrr` to iterate over 2 columns:

```
library(purrr)

data %>% 
  mutate(predicted = map2_dbl(alfa, beta, ~ rbeta(1, .x, .y)))

         mu    kappa     alfa       beta predicted
1 0.5484034 77.82304 42.67842 35.1446188 0.5618492
2 0.9445769 26.29399 24.83669  1.4572956 0.9805548
3 0.7216756 28.01233 20.21581  7.7965152 0.7686036
4 0.7216103 24.51660 17.69143  6.8251705 0.8851859
5 0.9873867 42.87690 42.33608  0.5408175 0.9991376
```

Answer (score 3):

The first argument to `rbeta` is the number of values you want - use the number of rows of data, not `1`.

```
data$predicted = with(data, rbeta(nrow(data), alfa, beta))
```

(`rbeta` is vectorized over the `shape1` and `shape2` parameters).

Or with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  mutate(predicted = rbeta(n(), alfa, beta))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `tibble` instead of `data.frame` you can do it at the same time you're defining the *mu, kappa, alfa* and *beta* columns:

```
library(tibble)
data <- tibble(mu = c(0.548403436247893, 0.944576856539307, 0.72167558981069, 0.721610257581108, 0.987386739865525),
               kappa = c(77.8230430114621, 26.2939905325391, 28.0123299600893, 24.5166019567386, 42.8769003810988),
               alfa = c(42.6784242067533, 24.8366949231, 20.2158147459191, 17.6914314530156, 42.336082882832),
               beta = c(35.1446188047087, 1.45729560943902, 7.7965152141702, 6.82517050372298, 0.540817498266786),
               predicted = rbeta(n(), alfa, beta)
)
data
## A tibble: 5 x 5
#     mu kappa  alfa   beta predicted
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 0.548  77.8  42.7 35.1       0.534
#2 0.945  26.3  24.8  1.46      0.846
#3 0.722  28.0  20.2  7.80      0.797
#4 0.722  24.5  17.7  6.83      0.653
#5 0.987  42.9  42.3  0.541     0.991
```

`tibble` is an enhanced version of `data.frame` and may worth take a look: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tibbles.html